# I want to save Map[String, String] to disk and later read it back as same type. Somehow I cannot find collectAsMap method with my sparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on Spark Scala and there is a requirement to save `Map[String, String]` to the disk so that a different Spark application can read it.

```
(x,1),(y,2)...
```

To Save:

```
sc.parallelize(itemMap.toSeq).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(fileName)
```

I am doing a coalesce as the data is only 450 rows.

But to read it back, I am not able to convert it back to `Map[String, String]`

```
val myMap = sc.textFile(fileName).zipWithUniqueId().collect.toMap
```

the data comes as

```
((x,1),0),((y,2),1)...
```

What is the possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you save it in parquet format? Then you can read it back & transform to any kinda object

Comment: I answered with the assumption that you are dealing with text, but I agree with @tauitdnmd. Since your data is structured, you might want to use DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a text file results in `RDD[String]`, so you will have to deserialize your string representations of the tuples.

You can change your Save operation to add a delimiter between tuple value 1 and tuple value 2, or parse the string `(:v1, :v2)`.

```
val d = spark.sparkContext.textFile(fileName)

val myMap = d.map(s => {
    val parsedVals = s.substring(1, s.length-1).split(",")
    (parsedVals(0), parsedVals(1))
}).collect.toMap
```

Alternatively, you can change your save operation to create a delimiter (like a comma) and parse the structure that way:

```
itemMap.toSeq.map(kv => kv._1 + "," + kv._2).saveAsTextFile(fileName)
val myMap = spark.sparkContext.textFile("trash3.txt")
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(d => (d(0), d(1)))
  .collect.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Method "collectAsMap" exists in "PairRDDFunctions" class, means, applicable only for RDD with two values RDD[(K, V)].

If this function call is required, can be organized with code below. Dataframe is used for store in csv format ant avoid hand-made parsing

```
val originalMap = Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)
// write
sparkContext.parallelize(originalMap.toSeq).coalesce(1).toDF("k", "v").write.csv(path)

// read
val restoredDF = spark.read.csv(path)
val restoredMap = restoredDF.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1))).collectAsMap()
println("restored map: " + restoredMap)
```

Output:

```
restored map: Map(y -> 2, x -> 1)
```